# Wordpress site images loading everywhere but on the clients' local office PC's

Tags: wordpress, image, caching, loading, local

We have finished up a site for a client using Wordpress as the platform. The site loads fine over cellular data, and in my office, and strangely enough when connected to the clients WIFI inside their offices.

However, as soon as I try to access the site on one of their office machines, usually connected via ethernet, images do not load. They 404 when opened in a new tab and are either a. blank when viewed in page or b. display the accessibility alt text. They do not display the broken link icon but display a rectangle. I've tried on many of their machines with the same result.

I have tried clearing cache, allowing permissions in chrome for almost everything, viewing in incognito and checking links to make sure they are correct. All links work just fine via WIFI.

This is horrible situation as it makes us look totally unprofessional, even though this issue is clearly something to do with their local server.

Their old site which was pure HTML from 2001 did not have this issue, so could it be something that we haven't added to the htaccess that we should of?

Thanks and please help!

Comment: Apart from checking in browser console what’s going on on the client side as already mentioned in an answer, I’d start by checking whether the requests actually reach the server ... _“This is horrible situation as it makes us look totally unprofessional”_ - well if you want to look otherwise, you might need to update your problem analysis skills.

Comment: I appreciate the frankness, I'm only a project manager so my web skills are really sub par, but I try to do what I can before approaching forums like this. I've replied below as none of the images had a www. prefix and this was the issue. The office server seems to default to trying to grab the images without that prefix. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If the image addresses are recorded wrongly in WP content in the database, then I would suggest you use the plugin "WP Migrate DB", to replace all URLs starting with `http://oriordanbond.co.uk/` with `http://www.oriordanbond.co.uk/`, that should be able to fix the problem without having to do redirects or additional server configuration. (Don’t forget to make a backup, in case something goes wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the browser developer tool to inspect the img tags. See if you can access the img src url directly clicking on the link. Use the browser debugger to find out the root cause. It might caching issue or broken url or mixed content issue.

Comment: I've investigated and there's a missing www. before each image - without the www. the site redirects to an IIS server - so we need to find a way to add the www. to the request URL of every image. An example: http://www.oriordanbond.co.uk/wp-content/themes/homepro/charity1.png loads perfect. http://oriordanbond.co.uk/wp-content/themes/homepro/charity1.png results in a 404.

Comment: you can fix this by adding a cname for www to yourdomain.com